# NSWorkspacedidmountNotify/probably generic NSWorkspace

Tags: objective-c++, nsworkspace

I'm an experience C/C++ programmer but new to ObjC++. I'm trying to catch the NSWorkspacedidmountnofification in a Mac OSX project.

I added my callback to my app delegate interface.

```
- (void)mediaMounted:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

The implementation includes

```
- (void)mediaMounted:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"mediaMounted volume change.");
}
```

In my applicationDidFinishLaunching, I add myself to the notification center.

```
NSNotificationCenter* ncenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
[ncenter addObserver: self
            selector: @selector(mediaMounted)
                name: NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification
              object: nil];
```

However, when I run and mount the disk, I see:

```
 2012-08-29 09:52:31.753 OSN[2203:903] -[OSNAppDelegate mediaMounted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101340af0
 2012-08-29 09:52:31.756 OSN[2203:903] -[OSNAppDelegate mediaMounted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101340af0
```

I confirmed that Instance 0x101340af0 is my OSNAppDelegate self, but I don't understand what  else I need to do so the selector is recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector should be:

`mediaMounted:` not `mediaMounted`.

Your implementation takes an NSNotification as a parameter, not nothing.

You can verify your selector via:

```
if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(mediaMounted)] )
{
  NSLog(@"Good to go");
}
```

**Example:**

```
// this selector
@selector(test)

// will call this method
- (void)test{ }

// but this selector, noting the :
@selector(test:)

// would call this method
- (void)test:(id)sender{ }
```

You can read about selectors [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html).